# Cannot start TTS (Text to Speech)

Tags: android

Ok basically I have everything set up and I have set up my onClick method many times, but this time it is set up in my main.xml file

```
    <Button 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_height="40dip" 
    android:layout_width="80dip" 
    android:id="@+id/speak" 
    android:enabled="true"
    android:visible="true"
    android:text="Speak" > 

</Button>
```

obviously it has other things to define its layout but that is one of the xml layouts inside my button, and for some reason every time I click on the button, it just closes the entire application, Why is that?
also If I set it up to add a onClickListener then the button just does nothing.

I would set up my onClick listener like this

```
    speak.setOnClickListener(this);
     public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.speak:
        doSpeak();
        break;
    }
}
```

and it still doesnt work.... So i just dont know what I am doing wrong

```
     package com.write.it;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
    import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class Speech extends Activity implements OnInitListener {
private EditText words = null;
private Button speakBtn = null;
private static final int REQ_TTS_STATUS_CHECK = 0;
private static final String TAG = "TTS Demo";
    private TextToSpeech mTts = null;
    private MediaPlayer player = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    words = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.wordsToSpeak);
    speakBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.speak);



    // Check to be sure that TTS exists and is okay to use
    Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
    checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(checkIntent, REQ_TTS_STATUS_CHECK);
}

public void doButton(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.speak:
        mTts.speak(words.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;

        }
            }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQ_TTS_STATUS_CHECK) {
        switch (resultCode) {
        case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS:
            // TTS is up and running
            mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
            Log.v(TAG, "Pico is installed okay");
            break;
        case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_BAD_DATA:
        case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_MISSING_DATA:
        case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_MISSING_VOLUME:
            // missing data, install it
            Log.v(TAG, "Need language stuff: " + resultCode);
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
            installIntent.setAction(
                TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installIntent);
            break;
        case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_FAIL:
        default:
            Log.e(TAG, "Got a failure. TTS apparently not available");
        }
    }
    else {
        // Got something else
    }
}

public void onInit(int status) {
    // Now that the TTS engine is ready, we enable buttons
    if( status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        speakBtn.setEnabled(true);
        }
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    // if we're losing focus, stop playing
    if(player != null) {
        player.stop();
    }
    // if we're losing focus, stop talking
    if( mTts != null)
        mTts.stop();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    if(player != null) {
        player.release();
    }
    if( mTts != null) {
        mTts.shutdown();
    }
        }
    }
```

I mean am i not setting the volume or setting or telling it to speak?!?!?, am I not telling it to do something it is supposed to do?..... the volume on my phone is on and the media volume is up, I have an HTC evo 4g so it should work.....
here Ill add another one with utterance and the onClick Method

```
    package com.write.it;


    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Locale;
    import java.util.StringTokenizer;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
    import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
    import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;


    public class Speech extends WriteitActivity implements OnInitListener, OnUtteranceCompletedListener {
private EditText words = null;
private Button speakBtn = null;
     private static final int REQ_TTS_STATUS_CHECK = 0;
private static final String TAG = "Word Guesser";
    private TextToSpeech mTts;

    private int uttCount = 0;
    private HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    words = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.wordsToSpeak);
    speakBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.speak);
    speakBtn.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    mTts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US);



    // Check to be sure that TTS exists and is okay to use
    Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
    checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(checkIntent, REQ_TTS_STATUS_CHECK);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.speak:
        doSpeak();
        break;
    }
}

public void doSpeak() {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(words.getText().toString(),",.");
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,
                String.valueOf(uttCount++));
        mTts.speak(getString(R.id.wordsToSpeak), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        mTts.speak(getString(R.id.wordsToSpeak), TextToSpeech.SUCCESS, null);

     }



}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQ_TTS_STATUS_CHECK) {
        switch (resultCode) {
        case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS:
            // TTS is up and running
            mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
            Log.v(TAG, "Pico is installed okay");
            break;
        case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_BAD_DATA:
        case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_MISSING_DATA:
        case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_MISSING_VOLUME:
            // missing data, install it
            Log.v(TAG, "Need language stuff: " + resultCode);
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
            installIntent.setAction(
                TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installIntent);
            break;
        case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_FAIL:
        default:
            Log.e(TAG, "Got a failure. TTS not available");
        }
    }
    else {
        // Got something else
    }
}

public void onInit(int status) {
    // Now that the TTS engine is ready, we enable the button
    if( status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        mTts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(this);
}
}

public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    // if we're losing focus, stop talking
    if( mTts != null)
        mTts.stop();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    mTts.shutdown();
}

public void onUtteranceCompleted(String uttId) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Got completed message for uttId: " + uttId);
    Integer.parseInt(uttId);
}



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things mixed up in your code, especially the part where you check the engine with a `StartActivityforResult()`.

Please see this example of a working TTS: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/TextToSpeechActivity.html

Also you did not assign any ID to the button (apparently?) Could it be, that another button is using the ID?

**/edit:**
First of all, merge both Activities. If you call `onCreate()`again, it will override the previous one. Then add `implements OnClickListener` and replace

```
speakBtn.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
```

with

```
speakBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Eclipse will tell you that you need to add an unimplemented method.

Comment: no another button is not using the ID but i'll see what i can do with the StartActivityResult()

Comment: Please post the layout xml, as it looks like there are more then one button, I guess that will help a lot.

Comment: I did assign an id its android:@+id/speak

Comment: there I changed it for the full xml layout for the button

Comment: I was just messing around with it and i just took out the android:onClick method in the xml layout

Comment: yeah I tried it but still not working when I press the button im going to try and use the tutorial on dev guide, I was trying to find something like that tutorial, change things around and stuff, thanks for your help

Comment: hey I coppied the google thing word for word, Changed the button name and it still didnt work....

Comment: Try creating a new project and try again - it should work (it works for me). Then you can modify the new project.

Answer (score 0):

If the XML code you copied at the top of your question is all you have to declare that button, then it is missing the id you expect (R.id.speak) in the handler...

I would suggest you add some debug prints in the `doButton` function see if that gets called correctly before going any further in the text-to-speech and so on.

Comment: i just took out the anroid:onClick method in the xml layout